# MVC4 Render Index View (index.cshtml) inside api controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've a mvc4 project where no index.cshtml or layout.cshtml is specified. It should be returned in a action of a api controller. I've only the index.cshtml (its a single page application). How can i get the rendered view as string. I don't use any `Controller`, just `ApiController`.

Example :

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public string Index() 
{
   return Razor.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Views/index.cshtml"));
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string?

Comment: All pages are distributed in div tag and your routing arrange in <div id="routingId"/>